# Tensorflow 1.15.4 Docker installation not working correctly

Tags: windows, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, python-3.7

I am trying to run TF in Docker but I have the following error:

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-046e52e45c8c>", line 1, in <module>
    ner = build_model("ner_bert_slav.json", download=False)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deeppavlov/core/commands/infer.py", line 62, in build_model
    component = from_params(component_config, mode=mode, serialized=component_serialized)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deeppavlov/core/common/params.py", line 95, in from_params
    obj = get_model(cls_name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deeppavlov/core/common/registry.py", line 74, in get_model
    return cls_from_str(_REGISTRY[name])
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deeppavlov/core/common/registry.py", line 42, in cls_from_str
    return getattr(importlib.import_module(module_name), cls_name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deeppavlov/models/preprocessors/bert_preprocessor.py", line 20, in <module>
    from bert_dp.tokenization import FullTokenizer
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bert_dp/tokenization.py", line 25, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1019, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import node_def_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_node__def__pb2
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/node_def_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/resource_handle_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 42, in <module>
    serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 560, in __new__
    _message.Message._CheckCalledFromGeneratedFile()
TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:
 1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
 2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).

More information: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06#python-updates

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1148, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 316, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 350, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v1 import audio
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v1/audio/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_audio_ops.py", line 11, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context as _context
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/context.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/protobuf/config_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import cost_graph_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_cost__graph__pb2
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/cost_graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 42, in <module>
    serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 560, in __new__
    _message.Message._CheckCalledFromGeneratedFile()
TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:
 1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
 2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).

More information: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06#python-updates
```

I tried reinstalling TF with

```
pip uninstall -y tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==1.15.4
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.4
```

but it still isn't working. Also, the `__version__` method outputs the following error:

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-11-65996cac02ec>", line 1, in <module>
    tf.__version__
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/module_wrapper.py", line 193, in __getattr__
    attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'AttributeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1148, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 316, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 350, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v1 import audio
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v1/audio/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_audio_ops.py", line 11, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context as _context
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/context.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/protobuf/config_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import cost_graph_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_cost__graph__pb2
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/cost_graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 42, in <module>
    serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 560, in __new__
    _message.Message._CheckCalledFromGeneratedFile()
TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:
 1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
 2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).

More information: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06#python-updates
```

Is there a step in the installation I am missing? I am using Jupyter notebook (jupyter/base-notebook:python-3.7.6) in Docker and restarted the kernel after reinstalling TF.

Comment: Are you on mac?

Comment: I am using Win10

Comment: cause these paths don't seem Windows to me and one more question is there any special reason to use tf 1.x?

Comment: I am using Docker on Windows, and installing it inside the Docker Linux container.  The TF version is from the requirements of a library I am trying to use

Comment: if you want to then you can get a pre-built container from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags/?page=1&name=1.15)

Comment: Hi @Veneta, Could you please try again by installing `protobuf 3.20` as mentioned in the error using the code `pip install protobuf==3.20`?